# what is the meanig and use of \n\t\t\t\t\ in php

Tags: php, html

Can any one please tell me that what is the meaning and use of : **n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t** in the following response from and dwr service.

```
\r\n\t\t\t                    \r\n\t\t\t                    \t\r\n\t\t\t                    \r\n\t\t\t                \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t                    \r\n\t\t\t                    \r\n\t\t\t                    \t\r\n\t\t\t                    \r\n\t\t\t                \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t
```

Above is a sample it also includes html according to design of the page. I really don't understand whats the sense of these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're [escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).  `\r` represents the carriage return, `\n` represents the newline (linefeed) and `\t` represents the tab.

Comment: Does this definition remains same in java.

Comment: Yeah: C, C++, Java, python -- very many languages use these escape sequences with very few differences among them.  They all have common representations for `\r`, `\n`, and `\t`.

Answer (score 6):

`\r\n` is a newline and `\t` is a tab.

Comment: But it never showed up in html. There is no gap between the html.

Comment: These need to be wrapped by double (not single) quotes to take affect. Also, by default, any multiple spaces are rendered as a single space in HTML. To make it show those, you need to use `<br />` instead of each `\r\n` and `&#09;` instead of each `\t`. I personally use the characters you mentioned to make the source of my dynamically created code look neat and readable.

Comment: So these are for the development purpose only to read the html, we will remove these before going to production server right.

Comment: Nope. That only makes the source code **visually** look better. Look at the source code of this page, for example, and `youwillseethatcodeisnotlikethis` `but instead it's like this`. These are those spaces.